# How to get game end result using API for twitch.tv, hitbox.tv etc game streaming sites?

Tags: javascript, php, api, streaming, twitch

I'm trying to integrate some game streaming site to my website. How to get game end result using `API` for `twitch.tv`, `hitbox.tv` etc game streaming sites? I need to know who or which team wins after a match ends. I there `API` for this? Or is there any mechanism to get the game end result?

Comment: Not sure if you saw these, twitch API is not in my field but there are some APIs out there like https://github.com/justintv/twitch-api among others when searching Google

Comment: all those streaming site has api's but they don't provide the game end result as far as I know or observed.